# Слетели настройки phpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

теперь при подключении пишет такую ошибку:

Connection to 'yourdeveloper.ru' failed.
Invalid descendent file name "https:".

Что это за ошибка ? И что делать

P.S. Сервер был http://vipweb24.beget.tech/ , есть другой домен yourdeveloper.ru ни к одному не могу подключиться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ето ви хотите создали новое подключение и оно не роботает или ето старое отредактированное?

Comment: У меня был открыт проект, я не знаю, что случилось, но он закрылся и его даже нет в прошлых, то есть он слетел, теперь хочу по новой подключиться к серверу

Comment: Перепроверте Все настройки подключения

Comment: я уже и новый проект создаю, данная ошибка появляется, когда жму тест конекшн

Comment: домен ви вводите начиная с https?
Может в етом проблема?

Comment: Ввожу с https и без, уже всяко разно пробовал

Comment: если возможно добавте скриншоти

Comment: Добавил, нажимаю тест ФТП конекшн - и ошибка

Comment: Возможно вам закрили доступ по FTP

Comment: web server root url поставьте просто слеш

Answer (score 0):

В advanced options включите passive mode

Comment: Можно поподробней пожалуйста, не могу найти где это :(

Comment: на вашем скрине под паролем